# How can I access SpreadsheetApp in a Workspace add on helper function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am making a Google Workspace add-on for Sheets, written in Apps Script. The goal is to let users search an index of the tabs in their spreadsheet. When I call SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() I get the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheets')" if I make that call anywhere but in my run command, onHomepage(), where I render the main card.

```
function onHomepage(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());
  })
  return createSidebar(e);
}
```

In createSidebar, I create a new card and add an input with an action of 'refreshSuggestions'.
createSidebar:

```
function createSidebar(e) {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Search Tabs'));

  // Create an input with a dynamic suggestion list.
  var action = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('refreshSuggestions');
  var input1 = CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName('searchInput')
      .setTitle('Search')
      .setSuggestionsAction(action);

  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  section.addWidget(input1);
  card.addSection(section);



  return [card.build()];
}
```

refreshSuggestions:

```
function refreshSuggestions(e) {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  var userInput = e && e.formInput['searchInput'].toLowerCase();

  var arrayOfSheets = [];
  tabs.forEach(function(tab) {

    if (tab.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) !== -1)
    arrayOfSheets.push(tab.getName());
  });
  arrayOfSheets.sort();

  return CardService.newSuggestionsResponseBuilder()
        .setSuggestions(CardService.newSuggestions()
        .addSuggestions(arrayOfSheets))
      .build();

  }
```

It's when refreshSuggestions is executed that I get the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheets')".

Is this because of the scope of refreshSuggestions?

I've seen some threads saying that an add-on needs to be bound to a sheet in order to access its data, but I don't understand how that could work for an add-on meant to be used on any open spreadsheet. And like I said, calling SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() works in my onHomepage function.

I have tried calling `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` in the getSheetsSelection() function of the example code provided in [`this Google Developer tutorial`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/translate-addon-sample#appsscript.json), and it works as expected, not returning a null object.

I have also tried changing the Oauth scopes in my manifest, which currently looks like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Get Tabs",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage"
      }
    },

    "sheets" : {}
  }
}
```

Comment: @LorenaGomez thank you, I updated my question. To make my code cleaner for myself as well I've renamed getContextualAddon() to createSidebar(). Either way, all I am passing is an event object "e"

Comment: After the `refreshSuggestions()` function, in the second row, you have `var sheets = ss.getSheets();` but I don't see `ss` defined in your script.